# Need help with a mIRC macro

Tags: mirc

I'm trying to make a script that will automatically says "see you later" as soon as one specific handle in a channel says the words "going home". I tried to do it on my own but got lost. Could anyone help me out?

Comment: mIRC's Help File has examples for almost every scripting event. I used it nearly exclusively when learning mIRC-Script.

Answer (score 1):

```
on *:TEXT:going home:#:{ msg $chan see you later }
```

Note that this would only pick up "going home", not "I'm going home". You would need to add more to it, like making it *going home* or something of the sort.

Comment: do I replace the * with the username? like bob:TEXT:going home:#:{ msg $chan see you later }

Comment: you may want to change it to `*going home*` otherwise it will ONLY match if the person types "going home" without ANYTHING before or after.

Comment: the first asterisk (`on *:`) refers to the userLevel. if you only want it to trigger for a specific user, use: `#:{ if ($nick == Bob) msg $chan see you later $nick ! }`

Comment: this goes in remote.ini and doesn't have to be activated somehow, does it? I can't make it work

Comment: Yes, this goes into the Remote tab of your Scripts editor. It won't trigger from your own input.

Comment: okay I think its almost working with on *:TEXT:*going home*:#:{ msg $chan later } , but how do I change this to only respond to a user named Sprig, for example?

Comment: @Matt: My comment above covers that.

Comment: @jnpcl I agree - that's what I meant to do in my original answer. It came out italicized instead of having asterisks around it. :)

Answer (score 1):

The script below should get you started with mIRC scripting.
It works with private message as well as an channel message (going home).

```
on *:text:*going home*:#,?: {
  if ($chan) { !var %target = $chan }
  else { !var %target = $nick }  
  if ($nick == sprig) || ($nick == Bob) { !msg %target see you later }
}
```

You could also use `!var %target = $iif(($chan),$chan,$nick)` instead of having the first two lines. The #,? means the *on text* event is happening in a channel (#) or a private message (?). To send a private message use the */msg*   command. The command prefix ! makes the script run the client version of the command opposed to a scripted overwrite of the command *alias msg echo -a You've overwritten /msg command* for example will prevent you from being able to use the /msg command which you do not want. Incase it has been overwritten I prefix most command calls with ! to ensure some of my data is not intercepted by an overwrite.  The || between the *if* calls means *or* as **if nick is sprig** *or* **if nick is bob** (|| = or).